# Is it good practice to require the type in a class template to respond to a certain func?

Tags: c++

The std lib has types in class templates that requires the type to override certain OPERATORS, for exmple, the type we use in std::map requires the type to support the < operator.

But is it good to require certain FUNCTIONS? Consider this silly example

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {
  T t;
  Foo() {
    t.push_back(0);
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<std::vector<int>> foo;
  return 0;
}
```

there i've created a class template Foo and it's type needs to have a push_back member func. Is this design acceptable/common to c++ coders?

Comment: your code is completely ok. but still if you knew somekind of a base class that has the push_back function and if you also knew that every class that goes with Foo will be extended from that base class, use a pointer to that base class. ( e.g. a `SafeRelease()` function for COM objects can be created in both ways like, `SafeRelease<COMInterfaceType>()` and `SafeRelease(IUnknown * i)`, where i prefer the second one )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is called a template policy (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)) and it's a perfectly legitimate and common design pattern for classes or functions.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Just document the requirements on template parameters when describing the class template.

Note that in your example, `T` actually only needs a `push_back` function if the default constructor `Foo<T>()` is used.  (As far as the language is concerned.  Your requirements could be stricter to be on the safe side.)

If you're using a recent compiler, you can also use `static_assert` to make sure most template parameter requirements are obeyed, and/or to make the error messages when a requirement is disobeyed more legible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on static_assert, perhaps with an example? Is this thing a part of the C++11 standard?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's fine. The standard does it all the time. As an example, consider [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) which, as your example does, presumes that its template type implements a `push_back` member function. While we still don't have [concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29) though, you had  better document your requirements. It also helps to name your template types in a meaningful way; so instead of `template <typename T>`, you might have `template <typename Container>`.